# Horizontal scrollview autoscroll is not working

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

I have used the following code to set auto scroll for a Horizontal scrollview. But auto scroll is not working.

```
horizontalScrollView1=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);    
        horizontalScrollView1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                horizontalScrollView1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

My Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layLandmarks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have dynamically add imageview to the linearlayout inside the horizontal scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the UI from a separate thread.  All UI changes need to be run on the main thread.  Something you can try is calling runOnUiThread method:

```
ActivityContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        horizontalScrollView1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, used your code, still auto scroll doesn't happen.

Comment: @Manikandan can you give me more detail on what you're trying to do? I've copied your code and after a second, the horizonal scrollview scrolled to the end

Comment: it just skips to the last element inside the scrollview. I want it to be autoscroll moving form one element to other, with a delay of 1 sec.